# jquery not working in internet explorer using mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

i have  a group of radio buttons that are generated on the fly from the db into a partial control then rendered on the page as html and they all have the same name 
now in firefox and chrome the following code works fine

```
$(".FlightSelectedRadio").live('click', function() {
    alert("after flight select");
    $("#ToisGarantueedBid").attr("disabled", false);
});
```

however in ie it doesnt work on the first select of a radio but only fires if u select something else ? any ideas wat the problem is ?

Comment: Are new radio buttons generated on the fly within the javascript on the page? If not then I'd use `$(function() { $(".FlightSelectedRadio").click(function() { alert("after flight select"); $("#ToisGuaranteedBid").attr("disabled", false); }); });`

Answer (score 1):

Lazarus, is right! The code you are writing should be executed after JQuery's page ready event fires which can be accomplished in two ways.

1) Like Lazarus

```
$(function() { 
     // your code here.
});
```

2) Or tying in to the document object ready event.

```
$(document).ready(
   function() {
       // your code here.
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah the radios are getting populated by jquery ajax call, i have managed to get it to work by using the change function isntead thanks for the help